# AngularJS pre-render (cache) Controller View with static data

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to pre-render multiple controllers with static data. 
My code structure

- Controller in app.js file ($scope.userList = localData.users)
- View in separate template file user_list.html (ng-repeat="users in userList")

My goal is to avoid flickering when rendering user_list view in angularJS on slow devices, such as phones.

Comment: use ng-bind rather than {{}}

Comment: What do you mean by flickering ?

Comment: Flickering - populating html DOM with elements, on devices such as iPhone 4s it looks messy. But when I re-visit my View, there is no flickering due to cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ofiris answer is correct, so I upvoted it. But it only solves part of the flickering, that of a template in its raw format before Angular has a chance to render it.

There are actually 3 states to the template:

1. When the template is raw and unprocessed
2. When the template has been processed by angular
3. When the template has had its data loaded by angular

`ng-cloak` resolves the transition from 1 to 2, but it cannot resolve the transition from 2 to 3, since it does not know when all of your data is ready.

Let's say you are loading up an object via `$resource` or `$http` and it will set a scope object `foo` to be "Jim". Here is how your 3 states look in the browser.

First state (pre-rendering):

```
<div>{{foo}}</div>
```

Second state (post-rendering, while ajax is running in background, maybe some processing):

```
<div></div>
```

Third state (all loaded):

```
<div>Jim</div>
```

So `ng-cloack` very much solves the transition from 1 to 2, and hides that ugly `{{foo}}`, but it won't help you with the flicker from nothing to "Jim".

For that, you would need some sort of flag of your own. I wrote a directive which I wrap all of my templates in (along with `ng-cloak`), called "loading". Each controller sets `$scope.ready = true;` when all of the data is ready for state 3. But it is very simple, you just need to wrap as follows:

```
<div ng-hide="!ready">
  <!-- all of your stuff here -->
  <div>{{foo}}</div>
</div>
```

and then your controller can do:

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,MyService) {
   MyService.get('/data',function(data) {
      $scope.foo = data.foo;  // or whatever else you do here
      // other processing
      $scope.ready = true; // this shows everything
   });
});
```

Comment: I would add that a common way to resolve promises before the controller is loaded is to use routeProvider resolve.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Yeah, I second @Ofiris thoughts here. The weakness of `resolve` is that you end up moving code into routes, etc. Comes down to a stylistic preference. Personally, I like anything that is part of the controller to be in the controller. Cross-cutting concerns, like auth/auth, I put in resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `ngCloak` [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable **flicker** effect caused by the html template display.

Try to place it on the list containing `div`.

If you would like to resolve your data before the controller is instantiated, you can use [routeProvider.resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) method, see [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOymS4?p=preview).